# How do you trigger the execution of C# code in SSRS when a text box is clicked?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

How do I run some C# code by clicking a text box on an SSRS report? How do I place a handler to capture the click events on the text box? I have looked at using the action in the text box properties but it only gives four options:

1. None
2. Go to report
3. Go to bookmark
4. Go to URL

Options 2 to 4 do not seem to do what I want. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't, and I would suggest that if you need to run server side code from your report, you are misusing reporting services. Perhaps what you actually want is a web form?

Comment: you can use atleast javascript, but not sure if that can cover your desired action.